# Precision calibration tools

Tags: analog, current-measurement, voltage-measurement, calibration

What "affordable" voltage and current calibrations tools are available? I'm specifically looking for

- Voltage (and preferably current) metering
- 0.05% Accuracy minimum (preferably 0.01%)
- 14 bit+ reading (preferably 16)
- Preferably 24V tolerant, though if it has a precision resistance meter too, I could scale it down sith some resistors.
- 1k samples pr second
- Exportable to a PC (preferably real time)
- Preferably with a DAC with similar performance.
- Retails for less than 1000$

Edit:
Forgot to add what I consider affordable (1000$ max!).
And by precision I'm really thinking of the ADC max out of the box sample errors. I mean you could theoretically have a 22 bit ADC with 10% off samples. I want to use this to calibrate other ADC/DACs.

Comment: 14 bits is 0.006%

Comment: Can you define "Affordable"? I'm working with some Agilent data aquisition modules (34970A) that are 22-bit (you said precision - 14 bits is a nice microcontroller ADC, not "precision" in my industry) that are $1500 for RS232/GPIB, or $1800 for USB/Ethernet.  Figure $500 or so for each (up to 3) mux or switch (20 channels or so) you want to add.  Is that "Affordable"?

Comment: This is an odd ose of the word "calibration".  Normally a calibration standard is a fixed voltage or current or resistance.  When you buy a precision scale, for example, it will come with a 5.00 gram weight to calibrate it.

Comment: Initially forgot to define affordable. 1500 is a bit too expensive as I don't really need 22 bits samples. I guess I was a bit generous calling it precision though. It's just that so many DAQs are rated with a rather high error percentage (even though the bit per sample resolution is high).

Answer (score 1):

The magic words to google are "process calibrator":

I found the [Martel PSC-4010](http://www.tequipment.net/MartelElectronicsPSC-4010.html) that retails for about US$1100 and has an RS232 connection.

Fluke sells them too but they are more expensive.